# Prove an inequality, knowing that $x,y,z$ are strictly positive real numbers

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

*question*

Let x, y and z be strictly positive real numbers. Prove that the inequality holds:

$$\frac{x^5+4x^2+3x+8}{(y+1)^2}+\frac{y^5+4y^2+3y+8}{(z+1)^2}+\frac{z^5+4z^2+3z+8}{(x+1)^2} \ge12$$

*my idea*

The first thought i had was using Bergstrom inequality, but then i realised i can't turn the fractions. I also tried using CBS but with no result.

The only thing i got and i think might be abit useful is using AM-GM:

$x^5+4x^2+3x\geq 3* x^3*\sqrt{12}$

The radical is of 3 order.

I dont know what else i shoul do. Hope one of you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Does brute force work? Like minimize the LHS minus the RHS, possibly after manipulating the inequality?

Comment: @Kakashi i dont really understand your idea and what do you mean by brute force....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM twice:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{x^5+4x^2+3x+8}{(y+1)^2}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{x^5+4-5x+4(x+1)^2}{(y+1)^2}\geq\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{4(x+1)^2}{(y+1)^2}\geq12.$$

We used the following AM-GM:
$$x^5+4-5x=x^5+4\cdot1-5x\geq5\sqrt[5]{x^5\cdot1^4}-5x=0$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4(x+1)^2}{(y+1)^2}\geq4\cdot3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{(x+1)^2}{(y+1)^2}}=12.$$

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how you used AM-GM? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Nice solution! There's a little typo $x^5+4-5x\ge 0$

Answer (score 4):

We prove the inequality by using the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

We observe that

- the numerator is an increasing function. Indeed, let's denote
  $$f(x) = x^5+4x^2+3x+8$$
  then
  $$f'(x) = 5x^4+8x+3 >0  \hspace{1cm} \text{for }x>0$$
- the denominator $x \mapsto(x+1)^2$ is an increasing function, then the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ is decreasing.

Then, WOLG, we assume that $x \ge y \ge z$, by using the rearrangement inequality, we have

$$\text{LHS} =\sum_{x,y,z} \frac{x^5+4x^2+3x+8}{(\color{red}{y}+1)^2} \ge \sum_{x,y,z} \frac{x^5+4x^2+3x+8}{(\color{red}{x}+1)^2} \tag{1}$$

And it easy to prove that
$$\frac{x^5+4x^2+3x+8}{(x+1)^2} - 4 = \frac{(x-1)^2 (x^3+2x^2+3x+4)}{(x+1)^2} \ge0 \tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$, we deduce that $\text{LHS}  \ge 12$ and the equality occurs if and only if $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: Great solution! We could assume $x>y>z$ cuz the inequality is cyclic? I mean, doesnt change by x->y, y->z etc

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic, yes, but because the function $f(x)$ is increasing and $g(x) = 1/(x+1)^2$ is decreasing

Comment: @NN2 Thank you so much for your answer! I have a question: is there any way to arrive at this inequality without using rearrangement inequality? Also, why do we need the first part with function in the way of proving the inequality?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Here is the reason why we need the first part. Suppose $x = \max \{x,y,z \}$, there are only 2 cases: $x \ge y \ge z$ or $x\ge z \ge y$. Take for example the first case, then we have $f(x) \ge f(y) \ge f(z)$ and $g(x) \le g(y) \le g(z)$ with $g(t) = 1/(t+1)^2$. Then
$$f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(z)+f(z)g(x) \ge f(x)g(x) + f(y)g(y)+f(z)g(z)$$
Same for the second case.